# How do I make a custom Flash component work with any font?

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts, components, flash-cs4

So we have a component we have written ourselves that deals with text display and translation between languages, reading translations from a file. Ideally what we would like to do is have this component be compatible with any font we can embed in the main .swf's library. What's the best way to do that?

Currently we are going down the route of having our component have an attribute for the font name, lets say 'Font1'. We drag the component into the .FLA file we want and then add a new font to the library called 'Font1' and set it to the typeface we want. This is proving to be inconsistent and problematic which implies it's not really an ideal way of doing it.

Is there anyway to achieve the feature we want? The key is flexibility, we want to easily support languages (hence the component) but we don't want design to be limited in their font selection. Its not practical to embed a range of fonts in the component for example, as it adds to file size and is restrictive.

Any ideas or solutions to this much appreciated. The component is written in AS3 and we are using Flash CS4.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Runtime font loading or runtime font embedding.
There are many ways to deal with this depending on your development environment. In that regard, FlashBuilder may offer you more flexibility than Flash CS4 actually.

A general approach could be to have a set of SWFs file, each embedded with a particular font. Of course, these SWFs shouldn't be loaded at start up.

When calling a font in your component, you would practically call a function that would load the corresponding SWF, adding the font to your Application Domain, therefore making it available to your component.

Here's an article that may help in clarifying the process
http://nochump.com/blog/archives/20

but a Google search such as Runtime font loading or embedding should bring out a lot more resources.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will certain look into it. But from the sounds of it this approach would need access to separate .swf files at runtime, is that correct? This isn't really practical for us as we have to submit a single .swf file to customers. However I fear that it might be the only way to achieve this. In addition I should point out that currently we only have access to CS4 and FlashDevelop.

Comment: As you're already aware, a single SWF file would mean having all the fonts in one file... On the other hand , several SWF files would mean far more flexibility as you would be able to easily add new fonts to your library.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I wasn't clear, I don't mind having all the fonts in the file I use my component in, but I'd like to be able to change them from file to file. So I use my component in FileA.fla, with Arial, Impact and Comic Sans, but in FileB.fla i want to use Arial, Times and Century Gothic.Does that make sense? I still want to pick fonts at compile time, but for the component to utilise different one depending on the chosen design for that project.

Comment: As far as I know you either load all the fonts in your .fla and end up compiling a bloated SWF or you load the needed fonts at runtime , which leaves you with a few extra SWFS. I don't know of any alternatives but anyone correct me if I'm wrong.